# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when using instantclick.min.js

Tags: javascript, mobile, drop-down-menu, shopify

I am using instantClick on my Shopify website for the main navigation menu on mobile.

I am having issues on mobile activating the instantClick script so that on click or hover the dropdown menu gets activated. This is only a problem when the page is initially loaded. It is not a problem once the page is loaded and has had a hard refresh or you click on another page. I am not sure which part of my code is being problematic. On Chrome its reading as an Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    at K (instantclick.min.js?11695154509883091683:1)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the webpage: https://www.latexforless.com

Here is the initial call for the mobile menu on my html:

```
<a href="#menu" class="mobile_nav dropdown_link" data-dropdown-rel="menu" data-no-instant>
  <div>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <span class="menu_title">{{ 'layout.general.menu' | t }}</span>
</a>
```

The script used at the end of my index page:

```
<script src="{{ 'instantclick.min.js' | asset_url }}" data-no-instant></script>

  <script data-no-instant>

  function inIframe() {
    try {
      return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  if (!inIframe()){
    InstantClick.on('change', function() {
      if (typeof ga == 'function') {
        ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname + location.search);
      }

      $('head script[src*="shopify"]').each(function() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = $(this).attr('src');

        $('body').append( script );
      });

      var facebookAnalytics = $('head .analytics').text();
      var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.text = facebookAnalytics;
      $('body').append( script );

      $('html').removeClass('remodal-is-locked');

    });
    InstantClick.init();
  }
  </script>
{% endunless %}
<script>
```

Comment: "Maximum call stack size exceeded." error means some function is going on in a neverending loop. Where is the beginning of `{% endunless %}` ?